# Change language with singleTask Activity

Tags: android

I have Activity A with launchMode="singleTask",  I check locale to change language in onCreate method. I go to Activity B to chose language to change and go back to Activity A.
                    But Activity A is singleTask so it doesn't call onCreate method and it can't update language. Sorry for my English. Help me, please

Answer (score 0):

Specify in your `AndroidManifest.xml` that your want Activity A to be notified about locale changes.

```
<activity
    android:name="..."
    ...
    android:configChanges="locale" />
```

See the Android documentation on the [`<activity>` tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config).

You can then override `onConfigurationChanged()` in your activity's class.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    System.out.println("Locale is now " + getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
}
```